# Air iOS Flash, what is the included folder path?

Tags: ios, flash, air, path, urlrequest

This is kinda silly but I can't seem to find the directory path for the included folder.
In Flash Cs6 publish setting, I included a folder which is located at c:\abc\def\ghi/xxx.

In this case, the path in iOS will be app://xxx?
To access a flle in the folder, what string do I exactly need to pass to the URLRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access applicationDirectory. In iOS standard directories native path like

```
app:/ means applicationDirectory
```

applicationDirectory - /var/mobile/Applications/uid/filename.app

applicationStorageDirectory - /var/mobile/Applications/uid/Library/Application Support/applicationID/Local Store

However you can access application directory file like

```
var applicationXMLFile:File =  File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("application_data.xml");
var applicationXMLUpdateFile:File = new File(applicationXMLFile.nativePath);
```

if we are trying access directly like

```
var applicationXMLFile:File =  File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("application_data.xml");
```

Sometimes it throws `SecurityError/IOError`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d9e

Answer (score 1):

Using a [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

If you want pass to URLRequest iOS Documents folder path.

try this:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.txt").nativePath);
```